# How to use a widget plugin in qt 3?

Tags: plugins, designer, qt3

For some reasons, I must work with Qt3 under SLES 11 SP3. I have written the following plugin:

```
// PixmapButtonPlugin.hpp
#include <qwidgetplugin.h>

class PixmapButtonPlugin : public QWidgetPlugin
{
  public:
    QStringList keys () const;
    QWidget* create (const QString& key, QWidget* parent = 0, const char* name = 0);
    QString group (const QString& key) const;
    QIconSet iconSet (const QString& key) const;
    QString includeFile (const QString& key) const;
    QString toolTip (const QString& key) const;
    QString whatsThis (const QString& key) const;
    bool isContainer (const QString& key) const;
};
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN(PixmapButtonPlugin)


// PixmapButtonPlugin.cpp
#include "PixmapButtonPlugin.hpp"
#include "PixmapButton.qh"

QStringList PixmapButtonPlugin::keys () const
{
  return QStringList() << "PixmapButton";
}

QWidget* PixmapButtonPlugin::create (const QString&, QWidget* parent, const char*)
{
  return new PixmapButton(parent);
}

QString PixmapButtonPlugin::group (const QString&) const
{
  return "Buttons";
}

QIconSet PixmapButtonPlugin::iconSet (const QString& key) const
{
  return QWidgetPlugin::iconSet(key);
}

QString PixmapButtonPlugin::includeFile (const QString&) const
{
  return "PixmapButton.qh";
}

QString PixmapButtonPlugin::toolTip (const QString&) const
{
  return "Pixmap button";
}

QString PixmapButtonPlugin::whatsThis (const QString&) const
{
  return "Button that takes the shape of its pixmap";
}

bool PixmapButtonPlugin::isContainer (const QString&) const
{
  return false;
}
```

I have finally copied the compiled shared library libplugins.so in the folder

```
/usr/lib/qt3/plugins/designer
```

The designer doesn't display the plugins anywhere and doesn't tell me that it couldn't create the corresponding widget either. I get absolutely no error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help at work from a senior developer and actually found a way out of this problem. The main issue here is to make sure that the plugin is ok. How can I check that everything is fine with my plugin? That's pretty simple.

First, compile the following simple application:

```
// PluginLoader.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <qlibrary.h>
#include <private/qcom_p.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QLibrary lib("/path-to-my-plugin/myPlugin.so");
  std::cout << "Load: " << lib.load() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Resolve: " << (lib.resolve("ucm_instantiate") != 0) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Second, activate some debugging tools for libraries: type the following commands in a console

```
export LD_WARN=1
export LD_VERBOSE=1
export LD_DEBUG=all
```

Note that there are many other options than "all" for the LD_DEBUG variable. Just type

```
export LD_DEBUG=help
```

to get more details (you will get the details as soon as you launch the above application).

Then, launch the PluginLoader application

```
./PluginLoader 2> loader.log
```

The file loader.log will then contain all the details regarding the libraries that are being loaded, in particular messages starting with

```
symbol lookup error
```

which indicate that something is missing in the plugin.

When the PluginLoader is happy, i.e. when it says

```
Load: 1
Resolve: 1
```

you are normally ready to use the plugin in the Qt Designer. To use it, copy it in the folder

```
/usr/lib/qt3/plugins/designer
```

or

```
$QTDIR/plugins/designer
```

which is the default folder for the designer's plugins. You may also be successful by setting the

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
QT_PLUGIN_PATH
```

appropriately.

Usually, you can also simply

```
ldd /path-to-your-plugin/myPlugin.so
```

This will show you which libraries this plugin was linked against. This can provide you with information about libraries that you may have forgotten ...

And a last comment. I am developing on SLES 11 SP3 64 bits. However, I am compiling 32-bits applications. In particular, the plugin is 32 bits. Before trying to let the plugin appear in the designer, make sure that the designer is the 32-bit version. Otherwise, the plugin won't appear in the list.

Note also that this process can also be applied to the production of Qt4 and Qt5 plugins (maybe modulo a few adaptions)!